# servicestack with asp.net core read web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, web-config, servicestack

How to read  *appsettings.json* or *web.config* with ServiceStack ASP.Net Core?

```
IAppSettings appSettings = new AppSettings();
appSettings.Get<string>("Hello");
```

does not find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ServiceStack's default AppSettings for .NET Core can read `<appSettings/>`, [SimpleAuth.Mvc web.config](https://github.com/NetCoreApps/SimpleAuth.Mvc/blob/master/src/Mvc/web.config) is an example project that uses this.

### Using .NET Core's IConfiguration config model

With the [new ServiceStack v5](https://forums.servicestack.net/t/myget-pre-release-packages-upgraded-to-v5/4749) that's now [available on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget) you can choose to instead use .NET Core's `IConfiguration` model with the new `NetCoreAppSettings` [IAppSettings](http://docs.servicestack.net/appsettings) adapter.

.NET Core's `IConfiguration` class is automatically pre-configured when running your .NET Core app using the recommended .NET Core 2.0 Startup config, i.e:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

Where you can request to get it injected into the Startup constructor and assign it to a property with:

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) => Configuration = configuration;

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseServiceStack(new AppHost
        {
            AppSettings = new NetCoreAppSettings(Configuration)
        });
    }
}
```

Then you can get ServiceStack to use it with the `NetCoreAppSettings` adapter as seen above.

This works as a normal `IAppSettings` which you can use to read individual config values, e.g:

```
public class AppHost : AppHostBase
{
    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
        SetConfig(new HostConfig
        {
            DebugMode = AppSettings.Get(nameof(HostConfig.DebugMode), false)
        });
    }
}
```

Or bind to complex Types using the `IAppSettings.Get<T>()` APIs.

An example .NET Core 2.0 ServiceStack v5 project that uses it is [NetCoreTemplates/react-spa](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/react-spa/tree/master/MyApp).

Comment: @BrianOgden no it uses a completely different AppSettings impl, but you should be able to [populate config directly from the reader](https://forums.servicestack.net/t/does-anyone-implemented-a-jsonfilesettings/2789/9?u=mythz)

Comment: thanks, I am not really following though, I am simply trying to do  new JwtAuthProviderReader { HashAlgorithm = "RS256", AuthKeyBase64 = //get value from appsettings.json } in my AppHost.cs file and I have no way of getting any configuration values

Comment: @BrianOgden you still need to use [Microsoft’s configuration classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration?tabs=basicconfiguration) just as you would normally which you can register in .NET Core’s IOC or assign it to a static variable, or AppHost instance variable, etc.

Comment: you are saying I will need to use property dependency injection to get a hydrated instance IOptions<MyConfig> into my AppHost class? Like so:   public Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions<AppSettings> Settings { get; set; }

Comment: @BrianOgden You could register just the `IConfiguration` itself as just another dependency. Please also see the updated answer to show how you can use the new `NetCoreAppSettings` AppSettings adapter in ServiceStack v5 that's now available on MyGet. Please review the [ServiceStack v5 changes](https://forums.servicestack.net/t/myget-pre-release-packages-upgraded-to-v5/4749) before upgrading.